# How can I make a shortcut on the keyboard to Page Up like CTRL+arrow up?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to create shortcuts to <kbd>PG UP</kbd>, <kbd>PG DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>HOME</kbd> and <kbd>END</kbd> using the arrow (cursor) keys modified by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

It is possible?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to make shortcuts that perform a page up, page down, home, and end (as in key-combinations)? Or do you want to "remap" keys to do those functions? I don't necessarily have your answer - but your request is pretty vague. Which Ubuntu are you using? Which version? What is your actual goal with this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want CTRL (or ALT) + PGUP mapped to the left cursor button,, and so on? Please show *explicitly* (ina formatted table) the mappings that you require.